# hot to play a song/sound in a WP7 silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

how to i play a song in a silverlight wp7 app?

i know how to do it in the xna framework with the MEdiaPlayer but i dont know how to make it in silverlight. it starte wicht the problem, that i dont know how to load the song as a content.

who can show me a code example?

in xna it looks like:

```
private void PlayMusic(Song song)
{
// Due to the way the MediaPlayer plays music,
// we have to catch the exception. Music will play when the game is not tethered
try
{
// Play the music
MediaPlayer.Play(song);

// Loop the currently playing song
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
}
catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are playing a `Song` from the phone media library the only way is with the `MediaElement`.

If you want to play an mp3 that your app has loaded, or stream one form online you can use the `BackgroundAudioPlayer`,  `MediaElement`, or `MediaPlayerLauncher`

You can set the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the `MediaElement` or the [Media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher.media%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) property of the `MediaPlayerLauncher`

If you want to use the `BackgroundAudioPlayer`, Microsoft has a lot of samples online for playing songs with the `BackgroundAudioPlayer`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394039(v=vs.92).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978(v=vs.92).aspx